# How to identify value change in one column in R?

Tags: r, database, medical

I plan to identify and extract the subjects who experienced drug change from old drug to new drug.
**In the code below, there are two types of drugs: A and B, type A is an old drug, while type B is a new drug, and B has different drug brands: 2,3 and  4.**
With the time passing by for each person, there are 3 patterns of drug change:

1. Patient 11 changed drug from type A to type B, and only the change from A and B is ok, but change from B to A is not regarded as change.
2. Patient 12 was always using type B, but he changed from brand 2 to brand 3.
3. Patient 13 changed from type A to type B, but he again changed from brand 2 to brand 3.

   ```
   df <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13),
                 drug_type = c("A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","B","B"),
                 drug_brand = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,3),
                 date = c("2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-13",
                          "2019-04-05","2019-05-02","2019-06-03","2019-08-04",
                          "2021-02-02","2021-02-27","2021-03-22","2021-04-11"))
    df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
   ```

So how should I filter the patients who changed drugs from  this dataset?
To solve this, I summarized the last date of use of drug for type A and the first date of use of drug for type B in two data frames. And I inner join them with id and filter with the condition that first date of type B is later than last date of type A, but this may only solve the change from type A to type B. I don't know how to identify all the patterns of drug change.

I haven't found any solution or any similar question about this, so I sincerely hope you can share your ideas with me. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could look at the transition of `drug_type` from "A" to "B", or include where the number of distinct `drug_brand` is greater than 1?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(any(drug_type == "B" & lag(drug_type) == "A") |
           n_distinct(drug_brand) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
Actually, I met another problem because there are 3 drug types in the dataset. Accurately speaking, in addition to transition of drug type from "A" to "B" or "C",  that the number of distinct drug_brand is greater than 1 only happens in drug type "B" or "C". I tried using   `filter(any(drug_type == "A" & (lag(drug_type)=="B"|lag(drug_type) == "C")) | (n_distinct(drug_brand)>1& (drug_type == "B"|drug_type =="C")))`, no error is returned, but I wonder if it fits the goal or if the codes can be more concise.

Comment: @NKevin Yes, you could simplify, instead of the OR `|` you could use `%in%`...for example, `(lag(drug_type) %in% c("B", "C"))` and `drug_type %in% c("B", "C")` ...let me know if this helps, or if needs further modification...I will login again tomorrow to follow up...

Comment: @NKevin There is a concern about the logic for `n_distinct...&`...since this is evaluated on each group of `id`...you may want `any(drug_type %in% c("B", "C")` after the `&`...this would mean if there is more than one `drug_brand` in the group *and* at least of the `drug_type` is either "B" or "C", then `filter` ...if this logic isn't correct, feel free to edit post again to clarify...

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. The simplified version worked so well! I learned a lot!

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind, could you please help me review the code I wrote in this link? It is associated with this question, but I met a bottleneck and I thought it would be better to post in a separate page. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71764346/how-can-fix-my-codes-to-make-my-filter-return-correct-results?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Is your end goal simply to filter out any subject who changed `drug_brand` or `drug_type`? If so, you can use a grouped filter with `dplyr::n_distinct()` to remove subjects with >1 brand or >1 type:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(
    n_distinct(drug_type) == 1,
    n_distinct(drug_brand) == 1
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it is a good idea, and I will try it!

Comment: I made a little revisement because I forgot to mention that if a patient changes from type B to type A, then it won't be considered as change