# How can fix my codes to make my filter return correct results?

Tags: r, database, data-science, medical

Here is the background information.
[How to identify value change in one column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717528/how-to-identify-value-change-in-one-column-in-r/71717939?noredirect=1#comment126767162_71717939)

Thanks to the help of two users, I gradually find the way to identify the drug changes in my data. However, now I need to check if there's a time gap before drug switch, if it is within 1 month, they will be kept.

So I used the following codes along with the codes used in the mentioned link.

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13),drug_type = c("A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","B","B"),drug_brand = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,3),
date = c("2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-13","2019-04-05","2019-05-02","2019-06-03","2019-08-04","2021-02-02","2021-02-27","2021-03-22","2021-04-11"))
```

Next, I used recommended codes to identify the subjects who switched their drugs.

```r
switch <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(any(drug_type == "B" & lag(drug_type) == "A") |
           n_distinct(drug_brand) > 1)
```

And then I tried only extracting the records on the switch day and the records 1 day before that, and I also created a column to show the calculated time gap between two dates for each patient.

```r
switch %>% 
  filter(drug_brand != lag(drug_brand)|drug_brand != lead(drug_brand)) %>%
  mutate(time_gap = interval(lag(date),date)/dmonths(1)) %>%
  filter(time_gap != NA) %>% filter(time_gap < 1)
```

It should have returned a result containing 4 records of 3 patients, but it returned nothing. I still haven't figured out why this happened because I checked my codes and they seem to be correct. Therefore, it would be great if you can share your advice to fix this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Replace `filter(time_gap != NA)` with `filter(!is.na(time_gap))`.

Comment: Your first `filter` could also be combined into: `filter(n_distinct(drug_type) > 1 | n_distinct(drug_brand) > 1, drug_brand != lag(drug_brand) | drug_brand != lead(drug_brand))`.

Comment: @MartinGal Thank you so much! Your suggested code worked so well. Could you please tell me why `filter(time_gap != NA)` failed?

Comment: `NA` usally produces `NA`. Check out `NA == NA`. Therefore the condition `time_gap!= NA` evaluates to `NA` and the filtering fails.

Comment: @MartinGal Thank you so much! I learned one more lesson